# Android emulator cannot find AVD file (even when setting ANDROID_SDK_HOME)

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator

I'm having some trouble getting started with Android development. I'm trying to launch the emulator from within the Android SDK and AVD Manager, but when I start a device I get an error saying that the emulator could not find the virtual device.

I've looked into this problem and found it's due to the manager saving the AVD file into one location but trying to launch from C:\User\USERNAME.android. In my case the manager is saving into C:\User\USERNAME\Downloads.android for some bizarre reason. I've tried moving the .android folder to my home directory. I've also created a new user environment variable called ANDROID_SDK_HOME and setting it to my home directory. (It shouldn't matter if I created a "user" environment variable as opposed to a "system" environment variable, right?). I even tried doing a symbolic link but the manager still creates files in my Downloads directory.

I am at a loss as to what could be happening. My only guess is that there might have been a change in the recent revision that voids the old fixes. Any suggestions?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810478/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-cant-create-avd-in-correct-file-location -- I had the exact same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting ANDROID_HOME in your System Variables?

Comment: I did, but it made no difference.